# Cannot install webpack@4.42.0 version

Tags: webpack, node-modules

I have installed `webpack@5.54.0` but I understood that version is not working for my project so I install it again `webpack@4.42.0`. but when I type `npm ls webpack` then the CMD display this error.

```
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.42.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^5.1.0, required by terser-webpack-plugin@5.2.4
```

actually, I don't know what is this error? how I can install `webpack@4.42.0` without this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You will allso need to downgrade terser-webpack-plugin version to 4.2.3.
Starting from version 5 terser-webpack-plugin webpack@4 [is no longer supported.](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v5.0.0)

```
npm install --save-dev terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
```

Comment: Yeah, I used the .env file with the "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true" code for my project to avoid this issue but it's not the exact answer to this issue so, I will try your answer soon and I will drop a comment about the result. Anyway, Thank you for your answer.

Comment: can you please check what is a terser-webpack-plugin version in package-lock.json?